# Find files, rename in place unix bash

Tags: bash, unix, rename, mv

This should be relatively trivial but I have been trying for some time without much luck.
I have a directory, with many sub-directories, each with their own structure and files.

I am looking to find all `.java` files within any directory under the working directory, and rename them to a particular name.
For example, I would like to name all of the java files `test.java`.

If the directory structure is a follows:

```
./files/abc/src/abc.java
./files/eee/src/foo.java
./files/roo/src/jam.java
```

I want to simply rename to:

```
./files/abc/src/test.java
./files/eee/src/test.java
./files/roo/src/test.java
```

Part of my problem is that the paths may have spaces in them.
I don't need to worry about renaming classes or anything inside the files, just the file names in place.

If there is more than one `.java` file in a directory, I don't mind if it is overwritten, or a prompt is given, to choose what to do (either is OK, it is unlikely that there are more than one in each directory.

What I have tried:

I have looked into `mv` and `find`; but, when I pipe them together, I seem to be doing it wrong. I want to make sure to keep the files in their current location and rename, and not move.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The GNU version of `find` has an `-execdir` action which changes directory to wherever the file is.

```
find . -name '*.java' -execdir mv {} test.java \;
```

If your version of `find` doesn't support `-execdir` then you can get the job done with:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}"/test.java' -- {} \;
```

Comment: The variable `$1`, `%` removes the shortest matching suffix `/*` -- it strips the file name from `$1` like `dirname "$1"` would do. `/test.java` is appended to that directory name.

Answer (score 5):

If your `find` command (like mine) doesn't support `-execdir`, try the following:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec bash -c 'mv "{}" "$(dirname "{}")"/test.java' \;
```

Comment: This will be safer for filenames with quotation marks: `-exec bash -c 'mv "$1" $(dirname "$1")/test.java' -- {} \;`