# Rename multiple files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have several files with the extension *.php in different subfolders in the folder /root/Hello. I try to rename all .php files to .html but I want to keep the structure i.e. the path to the file should remain identical.

I found all files with the following command:

```
find /root/Hello -name "*.php"
```

But I don't know how I can rename all files with *.php to *.html and keep the structure I think I must use:

```
-exec
```

But I don't which argument I should use with -exec

Comment: Look into [`rename(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, also see [Recursively change file extensions in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21985492/608639), [How do I rename the extension for a batch of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1224766/608639), [find a pattern in files and rename them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15290186/608639), [How to rename multiple files using find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227662/56041), [How to rename a file using find command](https://askubuntu.com/q/605125), [Find files, rename in place unix bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15007058/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use find:

`find /path -depth -name "*.php" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.php}.html"' _ {} \`;

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.